# CKEditor 3.1 - getClipboardData

Tags: ckeditor

Is there anyway to get the html clipboard data as done in getClipboardData() in plugin clipboard.js? Can anyone pls give me some guidelines to do that?

In previous version I can get data simply by calling CKEDITOR.getClipboardData() but this is no longer available in CKEditor 3.1.

Many thanks,

Kristin

Comment: By previous version, do you mean FCKEditor or CKEditor 3.0? Because I can't see anything in the changelog for 3.1: http://ckeditor.com/whatsnew/all

Comment: Yes, I mean 3.0 and 3.0.1. 
They do state it here: http://ckeditor.com/whatsnew
"#4379 : Introduced the new powerful pasting system and word cleanup procedure, including enhancements to the paste as plain text feature."

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why the function was removed from CKEditor's core, but the "paste from clipboard" functionality continues to exist in the [pasteText plugin](http://svn.fckeditor.net/CKEditor/tags/3.1/_source/plugins/pastetext/plugin.js).

It should be possible to execute the plugin's function directly programmatically, but I don't know how this is done yet.

As a last resort, you could copy the code that does the pasting.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The text acquired from clipboard is text only. I need to get htmlText (text + html tags), which was previously the return value of CKEDITOR.getClipboardData(). Do you have any suggestions for this?

Many thanks again,

Kristin

Comment: Ahh of course, it's called paste*Text*. I don't know where they hid the real "getClipboard" function. My only idea would be to cut out the clipboard fetching part from pasteText, as I'm quite sure it still contains the original HTML at some point. Sorry.