# Upgrade to CKEditor 3.1

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Does anyone else find the online documentation to CKEditor woefully inadequate?

I upgraded to [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) 3.1 (from v3.0.1) and lost my toolbar.  What other surprises can I expect?  Have you upgraded to v3.1?

Comment: I did it a week ago and didn't run into any surprises, but I agree that the documentation is a bit on the sparse side.

Comment: Yeah, the documentation is not CKEditor's strong suit yet. I ran across a function a while back that was silently removed from the API: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040716/ckeditor-3-1-getclipboarddata/2041048#2041048 that can happen but I would love to see it documented somewhere. (Correct me if I'm wrong and I just overlooked it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the new version of CKEditor constructor (CKEDITOR.replace) does not support the same configuration options as does previous versions.  I resolved this problem by removing properties from the object passed to replace() and then slowly adding them back until I found the offending options.